# Calculate the median per week in R

Tags: r

I would like to calculate the median per weekday of my `PV` variable. In other words, looking at the variable `PV`, it can be seen, for example, that it has three Fridays, that is, the calculation of the median will consider data from these three Fridays.

Thanks!

```
library(dplyr) 

df <- structure(
  list(Id=c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1),
       date1 = c("2021-07-01","2021-07-01","2021-07-01","2021-07-01","2021-04-02",
                 "2021-04-02","2021-04-02","2021-04-02","2021-04-02","2021-04-02","2021-04-03",
                 "2021-04-03","2021-04-03","2021-04-03","2021-04-03","2021-04-08","2021-04-08",
                 "2021-04-07","2021-04-09","2021-04-10","2021-04-10"),
       Week= c("Thursday","Thursday","Thursday","Thursday","Friday","Friday","Friday","Friday",
               "Friday","Friday","Saturday","Saturday","Saturday","Saturday","Saturday","Thursday",
               "Thursday","Friday","Friday","Saturday","Saturday"),
       DTPE = c("Ho","Ho","Ho","Ho","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","Ho","Ho"),
       D1 = c(8,1,9, 3,5,4,7,6,3,8,2,3,4,6,7,8,8,6,16,2,3), DR01 = c(4,1,4,3,3,4,3,6,3,7,2,3,4,6,7,8,9,2,6,7,3),
       DR02 = c(4,1,4,3,3,4,1,6,3,7,6,6,4,6,7,8,4,2,6,2,3), DR03 = c(7,5,4,3,6,4,1,5,3,6,2,3,4,9,7,8,4,2,6,4,3),
       DR04= c(9,5,6,7,3,2,7,4,2,1,5,3,4,6,7,8,4,7,7,4,3),DR05 = c(9,5,4,3,3,7,1,5,3,7,2,3,4,7,7,8,4,2,6,4,3)),
  class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -21L))

df<-df %>%
  group_by(Id, date1, Week) %>%
  select(D1:DR05) %>%
  summarise_all(sum)

x<-subset(df, select = DR01:DR05)
x<-cbind(df, setNames(df$D1 - x, paste0(names(x), "_PV")))
PV<-select(x, date1, Week,ends_with("PV"))
PV
  Id date1      Week     DR01_PV DR02_PV DR03_PV DR04_PV DR05_PV
  <dbl> <chr>      <chr>      <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>
1     1 2021-04-02 Friday         7       9       8      14       7
2     1 2021-04-03 Saturday       0      -7      -3      -3      -1
3     1 2021-04-07 Friday         4       4       4      -1       4
4     1 2021-04-08 Thursday      -1       4       4       4       4
5     1 2021-04-09 Friday        10      10      10       9      10
6     1 2021-04-10 Saturday      -5       0      -2      -2      -2
7     1 2021-07-01 Thursday       9       9       2      -6       0
```

Comment: Would `df %>% group_by(Id, date1, Week) %>% summarize(across(D1:DR05, median))` suffice? I can't tell if the other steps in your code for summing and renaming are relevant for your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```r
x %>%
  group_by(Week) %>%
  summarize(across(ends_with("_PV"), median))
# # A tibble: 3 x 6
#   Week     DR01_PV DR02_PV DR03_PV DR04_PV DR05_PV
#   <chr>      <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>
# 1 Friday       7       9       8       9       7  
# 2 Saturday    -2.5    -3.5    -2.5    -2.5    -1.5
# 3 Thursday     4       6.5     3      -1       2
```

If you want to combine all columns, one way is

```r
PV %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  select(Week, ends_with("PV")) %>%
  tidyr::pivot_longer(-Week) %>%
  group_by(Week) %>%
  summarize(Med = median(value))
# # A tibble: 3 x 2
#   Week       Med
#   <chr>    <dbl>
# 1 Friday       8
# 2 Saturday    -2
# 3 Thursday     4
```

Comment: Thank you r2evans. I think I didn't write the question very well, but actually I wanted to calculate the median of the day of the week, that is, there will only be three medians, one for Thursday, Friday and one for Saturday. To calculate the median on Saturday, for example, the days 03/04 and 10/04 will be considered, so we will have a median. For Thursday, 08/04 and 01/07 will be considered.  I don't know explained better now?

Comment: You're saying you want a 2-column result, `Week` and `PV` which is the median for *all columns combined* for each day of the week?

Comment: Exactly what you did there in the second answer, thank you so much r2evans!